# Strange spacing in inline listings (listings package)

Tags: spacing, listings

I am using the `listings` package to typeset some code.  I've defined a `lstlisting` environment, based upon the standard `Haskell` environment, and added a number of `literate` replacements, including:

```
literate={->}{{$\rightarrow{}$}}2
```

When the symbol `->` appears in a listing environment, my spacing around the symbol is preserved.  However, when it appears in an inline listing, the space after the `\rightarrow` gets eaten, resulting in `T a -> a -> a` looking like `T a ->a -> a`.  Does anyone know how I can avoid this behavior in the inline listings without also confusing the listing environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. I realize that it does not sound too complicated in this case, but any time you can save of those trying to help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using `literate` to replace the "symbol" `->` with `->` (note the addition of spaces surrounding the arrow. The reason being that spaces are treated differently in inline as opposed to display listings. Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{%
  literate={->}{{ $\rightarrow$ }}3
}
\begin{document}
Here is a display listing:
\begin{lstlisting}
T a->a->a
\end{lstlisting}
Here is some inline listing \lstinline!T a->a->a!.
\end{document}
```

Note the difference in spacing between `T` and `a` in the respective listing styles.

Answer (score 1):

@Werner's solution is fine, but adding spaces to the replacement will have different results in both `lstlisting` and `lstinline`. For example, if you replace `->` by, say, `->` and you have the following snippet:

```
a -> a -> a -> a
```

it will show up normally in `lstinline`, but it will show up with two spaces after the arrows in `lstlisting`, like this:

```
a ->  a ->  a ->  a
```

My solution to this was to define a replacement for `->` and another one for `->`:

```
{->}{{{\color{magenta}->}}}2
{->\ }{{{\color{magenta}-> }}}3
```

Note that the smallest replacement *must come first*, otherwise it won't work.